# How to save only changed columns in JPA spring-boot

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This has absolutely nothing todo with the duplicate linked question!

My problem is that JPA is trying to save all the fields, even though it has not changed them, which ruins some things for me on db2.

**The Entity:**

```
@Data  // Auto getter and setters by lombok
@Entity
@IdClass(TkmstpId.class)
@Table(name="TKMSTP")
public class Tkmstp implements Serializable { 
    // DMD column: Tkslsk: decimal(2)
    @Id
    @Column(name="TKSLSK")
    private Long slskNr;
    // DMD column: Tkknnr: decimal(7)
    @Id
    @Column(name="TKKNNR")
    private Long kundenr;
    // DMD column: Tknr: decimal(7)
    @Id
    @Column(name="TKNR")
    private Long tankNummer;
    // DMD column: Tkstat: decimal(1)
    @Column(name = "TKEVOL")
    private Long estAarsForbrug;
    @Column(name = "TKGDK")
    private Long gKode;
    @Column(name = "TKUDSSKY")
    private String udskrivKortJn;
    @Column(name="TKLV5DAT")
    private java.sql.Date leveringsDato_tklv5dat;
    // DMD column: Tkudssky: char(1)

}
```

**The handling:**

```
TkmstpId id = new TkmstpId();
                id.setKundenr(Long.parseLong(customer.getAccountNumber()));
                id.setSlskNr(1L);
                id.setTankNummer(customer.getContainerId());
                Tkmstp container = tkmstpRepository.getOne(id);
                if (container != null) {
                    boolean changed = false;
                    if (container.getEstAarsForbrug() == null || container.getEstAarsForbrug() == 0L) {
                        changed = setContainerEstimatedValues(container, customer);
                    } else if (container.getGKode() != 5L && container.getGKode() != 6L) {
                        changed = setContainerEstimatedValues(container, customer);
                    }
                    if (changed) {
                        tkmstpRepository.save(container);
                        System.out.println("updated container info on: customer: " + id.getKundenr() + " and container: " + id.getTankNummer());
                    }
                }
```

**SQL generated:**

```
Hibernate: update tkmstp set tklv5dat=?, tkudssky=?, tkevol=?, tkgdk=? where tkknnr=? and tkslsk=? and tknr=?
```

**SQL I'd would like**(Without tklv5dat)
update tkmstp set  tkudssky=?, tkevol=?, tkgdk=? where tkknnr=? and tkslsk=? and tknr=?

**The Error:**
java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0407] Null values not allowed in column or variable TKLV5DAT.

Thanks in advance all...

**Application.properties jpa settings:**

```
 spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = false spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
```

Comment: What was in TKLV5DAT before the update ? Was it null or did it contain a value ?

Comment: @PaulNUK it's null, weird i know, but that's because JPA havn't been used for this before, and they could save the value, behind restrictions.

Comment: You never wish to update those fields ? Or do you want to update them sometimes and sometimes no ?

Comment: @BrankoIlic I'd like to update them some times, which is why @Modifying@Query seems bad.

Comment: It is your JPA provider that is doing this, not "JPA". I wonder which JPA provider that is?

Comment: @DN1 did an update with some application properties, is this it? :)

Comment: So you are using HIBERNATE. This is well known to update ALL fields on an UPDATE. Other JPA providers that use bytecode enhancement don't do that and just update the changed fields

Comment: @DN1 suggestions is welcome thanks :)

Comment: @DN1 Can you please make your comment a question?

Comment: @DN1 I meant answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

imO this must not be allowed, either the field is transient and not saved at all or if you use the ORM-Layer, the object must be saved together with all its fields to make sure the integrity of the Object is guaranteed. So I think the only way to achieve what you want is to use explicite update statements.

```
em.createQuery(
   "update tkmstp t 
       set t.tkudssky=:tkudssky, t.tkevol=:tkevol, t.tkgdk=:tkgdk 
       where t.tkknnr=:tkknnr and t.tkslsk=:tkslsk and t.tknr=:tknr")
   .setParameter(":tkudssky",container.tkudssky)
   .setParameter(":tkevol",container.tkevol)
   .setParameter(":tkgdk",container.tkgdk)
   .setParameter(":tkknnr",container.tkknnr)
   .setParameter(":tkslsk",container.tkslsk)
   .setParameter(":tkudssky",container.tkudssky)
   .executeUpdate();
```

The other possibility would be to use one update direct using DBMS-Means to set TKLV5DAT to the correct default value. The positive side-effect would be, that DBMS-Checks and JPA-Checks could be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the column value is null when it's loaded, so the least invasive fix is to make the column on the database nullable.